# Do the same parameters of PostgreSQL optimization apply to YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Can I also set in YB the usual optimization parameters I set in PostgreSQL, and will these have any performance benefit, like `shared_buffers`, `effective_cache_size`, `work_mem`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the parameters. If they control a structure used by the YugabyteDB layer or not.
Examples:
`shared_buffers` and `effective_cache_size` are not used by YugabteDB because all caching is on the DocDB layer. The PostgreSQL used on the query layer is stateless, which means it must obtain data from the DocDB layer, because that is where the current state is kept.

`work_mem` tuning is valid with YugabyteDB YSQL, because the work and the memory it takes for sorts, hash joins and CTE are taking place in YSQL just like it does in PostgreSQL..